# Cannot remove item from ISet collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following class:

```
public class Test
{
  ...
  public ISet<CategoryAssignment> Categories { get; } = new HashSet<CategoryAssignment>();

  public void LinkWithCategory(Category category)
  {
    Categories.Add(new CategoryAssignment(category, this));
  }

  public void RemoveCategoryLink(int categoryId)
  {
    var categoryAssignment = Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId);
    Categories.Remove(categoryAssignment);
  }
}
```

But when calling the `RemoveCategoryLink()` method it get following error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Why do the foreign keys in the CategoryAssignment class have to be nullable?
How do I remove an item from a ISet collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with MethodMan that this question seems duplicate of a question asked by Masaud, I feel that the following code of yours has an issue:

```
public void RemoveCategoryLink(int categoryId)
  {
    var categoryAssignment = Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId);
    Categories.Remove(categoryAssignment);
  }
```

Issue: FirstOrDefault - this method either returns first match or default value (which in your case can be null) if no match is found. So your categoryAssignment object might be null if this scenario happens.
In that situation the following statement:

```
Categories.Remove(categoryAssignment);
```

will throw an error. I don't imply that the error you are getting is coming from this but its worth a try to modify your code:

```
public void RemoveCategoryLink(int categoryId)
      {
        var categoryAssignment = Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId);
        if(categoryAssignment!=null)
           Categories.Remove(categoryAssignment);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. But that was not the problem. I was hoping for an one liner to work around the problem described in the linked question, since it didn't really offer a reasonable simple solution

Comment: I get that my answer might not solve your problem but it points to a possible error you may get at some point.